# GPIO input and output levels

Tags: hardware, peripherals, output

I have some basic questions, sorry, I have'nt found this.

1. What are output levels of GPIO (Raspberry Pi) I mean the voltage
   ranges of low and high for input/output
2. What is the maximum current that one GPIO output can handle
3. Can I power LED only using GPIO output (with resistor) (with no +5V
   pin)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the Electrical Specifications of GPIO pins?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60218/what-are-the-electrical-specifications-of-gpio-pins)

Answer (score 4):

Per the [elinux wiki](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#General_Purpose_Input.2FOutput_.28GPIO.29), the GPIO pins are configurable to source or sink from 2mA to 16mA each, 3.3V (not 5V tolerant).

They also have [GPIO tutorials](http://elinux.org/RPi_Tutorial_Easy_GPIO_Hardware_&_Software), one of which demonstrates driving a low power LED directly from the output with no 3.3V or 5V connection used.

Comment: Thank you and do you know the ranges of high and low for 3v3 logic then?

Comment: I do not have an authoritative answer, but this thread http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=8668 indicates "16mA with an output voltage of 2.3V sourcing and 17 mA with an output voltage of 0.4V when sinking."

Answer (score 3):

The Pi's GPIO are 3V3.  There is no authoritative source for voltage levels.  For the likely voltage levels see http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications

A GPIO can output considerably more than 16mA.  Whether it is safe to do so for any length of time I don't know.  I think I have measured sourcing and sinking about 40 mA from a single GPIO, but I'll need to check my figures.

Yes, you can power LEDS directly from the 3V3 GPIO.  Best to use a resistor to avoid the risk of burning the LED out.

Answer (score 1):

2. What is the maximum current that one GPIO output can handle

Besides the given limits **per** pin a **total** limit for all GPIO pins of 50 mA is noteworthy and should be considered. The total current sourced or sinked from **all GPIO together** (the sum of all pins) should not exceed the limits of the 3.3V rail. [Raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply) states: *The GPIO pins can draw 50mA safely, distributed across all the pins; an individual GPIO pin can only safely draw 16mA.*

3. Can I power LED only using GPIO output (with resistor) (with no +5V pin)?

Yes it is possible - since GPIO pins can both sink and source a current, a load can be switched to either VCC or GND. Just consider to connect the LED (with series resistor) to a GPIO pin and to GND. Set the pin to high (1) to turn on the LED.